# PHP array_rand weird behaviour

Tags: php, random

I was trying to create a simple password generator and noted that `array_rand()` returns the same results. Here is the code:

```
<?php
function generatePass() {
    $password = '';
    $a = explode(' ', 'q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j k l z x c v b n m');
    for($i=0; $i < rand(1,200); $i++) {
        $password .= $a[array_rand($a)];
    }
    return $password;
}

$r = 0;

while ($r <= 10000) { #generating 10 000 passwords
    $total[] = generatePass();
    $r++;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($total);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The `$total` array basically contains the same results repeated over and over again; if I refresh the page, only the order of elements changes, and not their values.

The question is: is this an expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?
Thak you for your attention.

Comment: ok. the `array_rand()` function uses a stupid algorithm that could cause issues like you are experiencing. try to shuffle the `$a` variable after you exploded it. `shuffle($a);`

Comment: I suspect you're running into problems because array_rand actually uses a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) and hasn't been seeded. I'm not going to make this an answer since I'm not a php expert, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: @Schalk Keun, `shuffle($a)` didn't affect the behaviuor of `array_rand()`, still having repeated results. Thank you for your advice though!

Comment: Could you show an example of repeated values? Are you saying that the first array element is identical to the others?

Comment: @Jack here is the screenshot http://joxi.ru/ZrJN893Svv33rj

Comment: Those values all look different to me ...

Comment: @Jack It's in the top right of the screen. Here is another way to check the results:
`echo count($total);
echo '<br/>';
echo count(array_unique($total));
?>`
Please paste this to the end of the script that I posted in the question.

Comment: Could it be that you're using Windows? If so, this is likely due to the awful linear congruential that libc rand uses on Windows. Try using mt_rand() instead. For password generation in particular you must use cryptographic randomness though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reseed the random number generator with [`srand()`](http://php.net/srand) just prior to calling `array_rand`.

```
srand();
$password .= $a[array_rand($a)];
```

Comment: "As of PHP 4.2.0, there is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() [...] as this is now done automatically."

Comment: I don't think this is how rand() works, but at this point I can't produce "evidence" for that statement.

Comment: Yes, this is has helped. Calling `srand(mt_rand())` before `array_rand()` actually worked! The documentation says though that there is no need to call `srand()` since 4.2.0 and yet I'm running PHP 5.6.3 I need to call it in order to randomize the seed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be your PHP version. I just copied your code into my localhost server and it worked fine. I'm using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7, you should try it or a newer version.

[image]

By the way, if you can't update your PHP version, use this modified version of your code:

```
<?php
function generatePass() {
    $password = '';
    // Put all letters into an array.
    $letters = array('q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m');
    for($i=0; $i < rand(1,200); $i++) {
            // Select a random letter with rand() command inside the brackets of the array.
        $password .= $letters[rand(0,25)];
    }
    return $password;
}

$r = 0;

while ($r <= 10000) { #generating 10 000 passwords
    $total[] = generatePass();
    $r++;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($total);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer; I run the code you posted and the passwords are still repeated: I checked four and each of them is repeated 11 times. PHP 5.6.3 on XAMPP.

Comment: How are you checking? Here is not repeating. See the image: [link](http://puu.sh/gGy9r/25a4ead003.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seeding the random generator isn't needed since version 4.2.0

Try using mt_rand() for a better generation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

Edit:

I think you actually want

```
$a = explode(' ', 'q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j k l z x c v b n m');
$end = mt_rand(1,200);  
$password = '';
for($i=0; $i < $end; $i++) {
    $password .= $a[array_rand($a)];
}
```

Comment: "The array basically contains the same results repeated over and over again" ... Just changing to `mt_rand()` doesn't answer that question.

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.6.3 yet I need to call `srand()` in order to randomize the result.

Answer (score 0):

I took the time for you and wrote the generator.
I got it to generate 10000 unique passwords and code is efficient:

```
<?php

function generatePass() {
    $password = '';
    $lib = 'q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j k l z x c v b n m';
    $a = explode(' ', $lib);
    //remove random char
    for($i=0; $i < mt_rand(1,49); $i++) {
        shuffle($a);
        //get Random Char
        $password .= $a[mt_rand(0,count($a)-1)];
    }
    return $password;
}

$len = 10000;  // total number of numbers
$range = array();
foreach(range(0, $len - 1) as $i){
    while(in_array($num = generatePass(), $range)){}
    $range[] = $num;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($range);
echo '</pre>';
```